# How to map <A-h> without opening gvim help?

Tags: key-bindings, gvim

I would like to create a custom mapping for the `<A-h>`, i.e. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> key combination.

```
nnoremap <silent> <A-h> …
```

However unlike `<A-l>`, this particular key combination **opens the `gvim` Help menu.**

How can I overwrite this standard `gvim`/window manager behaviour and still use a `<A-h>` mapping?

Answer (score 1):

```
" Disable Alt+[menukey] menu keys (i.e. Alt+h for help)
set winaltkeys=no
```